# how to get IVersionedTable from IVersionedWorkspace

Tags: arcobjects

I'm creating a custom Audit History component that will show old values (base values) and the new values (delta versioned tables).

I have been able to get the ObjectIDs of different change types between the base and delta tables changes such as:

esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeInsert

esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeDeleteNoChange

esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeUpdateNoChange

etc.

but I can't figure out how to access the actual versioned table (IVersionedTable - I'm assuming) so that I can compare each field's value to the base table (If there was an update, I need to know which field was updated, and the difference between the 2 values). Or, is there a better way of doing this?
Am I on the right track?

```
private static void getVersionedFeature(string parentVersion, string specificVersion)
    {
        IWorkspace pWorkspace = connectToAtlasEditSDE();
        IVersionedWorkspace pVersionedWorkspace = (IVersionedWorkspace)pWorkspace;
        //get a enumeration of all the versions on the versioned workspace
        IEnumVersionInfo enumVersionInfo = pVersionedWorkspace.Versions;
        enumVersionInfo.Reset();
        IVersionInfo versionInfo = enumVersionInfo.Next();
        while (versionInfo != null)
        {

            string versionName = versionInfo.VersionName;
            if (versionName == parentVersion)
            {
                IEnumVersionInfo childrenVersionInfo = versionInfo.Children;
                IVersionInfo childrenInfo = childrenVersionInfo.Next();
                while (childrenInfo != null)
                {
                    string childName = childrenInfo.VersionName;
                    if (childrenInfo.VersionName.Equals(specificVersion))
                    {
                        // get table here?!
                    }
                    childrenInfo = childrenVersionInfo.Next();
                }
            }
            versionInfo = enumVersionInfo.Next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you referenced this? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#72dfe883-e4d7-4925-835c-02bc513f91aa.htm

Comment: Oh man, don't know how I missed that. Thanks! Exactly what I needed @Brad

Answer (score -1):

Reference this documentation:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#72dfe883-e4d7-4925-835c-02bc513f91aa.htm